# Split file with commas, storing values in an 2-d array

Tags: c

Currently working on how to split a .csv file with ",". Then creating a 
2-D array to store the Alphabet and the number together. As it stands, the code below outputs: "a,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,". Also, what is the appropriate data type to declare the 2-D array since the values would be Char and int? Furthermore, I know this is a duplicate question because I've not found previous questions helpful. A simple explanation would be great and appreciated, explanation on how to split the file with this piece code would be perfect "%*[^,]" if possible. Thanks in advance.

Sample contents of the .csv file below.

```
A,1
B,2
C,3 
.....
```

The program:

```
char single;
/* char array[26][2];  I was thinking the 2-d array would be declared like that. */

while ((single = fgetc(fpointer)) != EOF)
{
    fscanf(fpointer,"%*[^,]");
    printf("%c",single);
}
fclose(fpointer);


    ............................................................
    edit code: With strtok() and fgetc()
    ............................................................

    //char single;
    char s[26] = ",";
    char *token;
    char str[100];


    while (fgets(str,100,fpointer))
    {
            while((token = strtok(NULL, s)) != NULL)
            {
                    printf(" %s\n", token);
            }
    }

    fclose(fpointer);
```

Comment: You will need to declare an array of structures holding two fields: a character and a number. As for the input, read the file line by line with `fgets()` and then split it with `strtok(",")` (some programmers hate this function, but it should be ok for this project). Alternatively, if there are no spaces before or after the comma, use `fscanf(..., "%c,%d", ...)`.

Comment: Okay, I tired implementing the strtok but now it doesnot output anything

Comment: Dis you read what I said about `fgets()`?

Comment: Yeah i did try reading the file line by line with fgets. I edited the above code.

Comment: You didn't. You still use `fgetc`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to hit edit. I did it now. I'm not exactly if i'm right

Comment: Now, you need to read a tutorial about `strtok`, because that's not how it is used.

Comment: @mac I've answered one of your posts earlier about this. You need to use an array of structs for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct
{
    char charVal;
    int intVal;
}SplitValue;

SplitValue result[50];
int count = 0;

FILE *myFile = NULL;
fopen_s(&myFile, "mycsvfile.csv", "r");
char single[100];
if (myFile != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(single, 100, myFile) != NULL)
    {
        // store the first char value
        result[count].charVal = single[0];

        // store the int value as string
        char intval[25];
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 2; single[i] != '\n'; ++i)
        {
            intval[i - 2] = single[i];
        }
        intval[i-2] = 0;

        // convert the string to int, either using atoi or sscanf
        result[count].intVal = atoi(intval);

        // get ready for the next item
        count++;
    }
    fclose(myFile);
}

if (count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("Char value: %c and int value: %d\n", result[i].charVal, result[i].intVal);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `i < single[i] != 0`, really?

Comment: Oops! Im sorry, I edited the answer. fgets actually returns string ending with newline and then null.

Comment: Yes, I am different mac :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution, considering comments from DYZ and RoadRunner. Hope it helps somehow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct charIntPair {
    char alpha;
    int  value;
} charIntPair_t;

#define MAX_ALPHABET_LENGTH 26
charIntPair_t myAlphabet[MAX_ALPHABET_LENGTH];
int alphabetLength = 0;

int main() {

    FILE *fp = fopen("mycsvfile.csv","r");

    if (!fp)
        return 1;  // File could not be opened.

    char line[100];
    for (alphabetLength=0; alphabetLength < MAX_ALPHABET_LENGTH && fgets(line,100,fp); alphabetLength++) {
        int elementsRead = sscanf (line,"%c,%d",
                    &myAlphabet[alphabetLength].alpha,
                    &myAlphabet[alphabetLength].value);
        if (elementsRead < 2) // not a valid char/int-combination?
            break;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<alphabetLength; i++) {
        printf("element %d is (%c,%d)\n", i, myAlphabet[i].alpha, myAlphabet[i].value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It expects that the character is the first element in a line and that it is immediately followed by a `,`. The number may have spaces upfront. The following input yields the following output:

```
A,1
B,2
C, 3
D,15
E,17

=>

element 0 is (A,1)
element 1 is (B,2)
element 2 is (C,3)
element 3 is (D,15)
element 4 is (E,17)
```